# web.config and authentification, authorization, location

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking to create a web.config file and I'm a little confused about which order do which tags go. I have 2 roles: testers and previewers.

Here's what I'm looking to do:

1) use the forms authentification tag with url "Login.aspx"

2) use the location tag to say that the directories /AppPages and /AppServices are only accessible to testers (ie. deny *, ?, previewers and allow authentificated testers only, deny everyone else)

3) use the location tag to say that the directories /Scripts and /Styles is only accessible to testers and previewers and deny everyone else

4) how do I make it so that all previewers who attempt to look into the /AppPages or /AppServices pages get rerouted to a custom page.

I have the following web.config file:

```
<system.web>

  <connectionStrings>
    ...............
  </connectionStrings>

  <roleManager enabled="true"/>

  <authentication mode="Forms">    
     <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
     </forms>
  </authentication>

  <authorization>
     <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>

  <location path="AppPages"> //same for AppServices
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
            <deny users="?"/>
        <allow roles="tester" />
        <deny roles="previewers" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web
  </location>

  <location path="Scripts"> //same for Styles
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
          <allow roles="previewers" />
          <allow roles="tester" />
          <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</system.web>
```

What I'm looking to do is have all users be redirected to the preview page and if the user is logged in as a tester then he'll be able to move on to the app pages while previewers will not.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About different login pages... As far as I know there's not a direct simple way to do this in asp.net.. There's just a variety of paths you can take to achieve it :-) Here's a post that outlines a fairly simple solution.. http://forums.asp.net/t/1348477.aspx

as far as the authorization rules it's kind of like a switch statement with breaks.. The first rule that applies to a current users state when accessing the site is the one applied and it stops processing any more... So for example this

```
<deny users="*" />
<deny users="?"/>
<allow roles="tester" />
<deny roles="previewers" />
```

should probably go

```
<deny users="?"/>
<allow roles="tester" />
<deny users="*" />
```

otherwise that first line will just deny everyone no matter what.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301390.aspx

Comment: Thanks. What about the Location tag? does its order matter, did I put it in the right order?

Comment: Don't have those enclosed in the existing <system.web> tag they are just on there own as children of the configuration element

<configuration>
.....
<location>
...
</location>
<system.web>
...
</system.web>

that or you can just put web.config files in the specific directories and just specify the authorization information there.
<